# Can't switch to jquery-mobile page

Tags: jquery-mobile

As the title says I can't show my "pagetwo"  when a table with data-role="table" has been shown on "pagetwo". The only way of switching to "pagetwo" is by deleting the property from the table. So can please someone help me showing "pagetwo"  without deleting the data-role?

```
<!--Page 1--->
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
    <a href="#pagetwo">Go to Page Two</a>
    <form id="postForm" method="post" action="<%= Url.Action("SaveAudit") %>">
        <table data-role="table" class="ui-responsive" id="contractList">
        </table>
        <button type="submit" form="postForm" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    </form> 
</div>


<!--Page 2--->
<div data-role="page" id="pagetwo">

<a href="#pageone">Go to Page One</a>
    <table data-role="table" class="ui-responsive" id="procesList">
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
$('#' + curSheet + 'List').table();
```

does the trick